# Customized kernel shows one cpu in core2duo

Tags: linux, debian, kernel

I have installed Debian 8 in my Core2Duo system.

lscpu shows 2 cores are available- 0,1

To build my customized kernel, I have downloaded kernel 3.18.21 from kernel.org. I have followed this document  [kernel compile](http://www.ramkitech.com/2012/04/how-to-compile-kernel-step-by-step.html) to compile my customized kernel.

It is successfully build, but the problem I am facing is after I build my customized kernel, lscpu shows only one CPU - 0. Where is the other CPU 1?

I have checked bios, there is  no change before and after kernel compile.

During booting time, there was error. 
It shows **systemd-modules-load.service loaded failed failed    Load Kernel Modules**

```
$ systemctl status systemd-modules-load.service
systemd-modules-load.service - Load Kernel Modules
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-modules-load.service; static)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2015-09-08 19:47:02 IST; 36min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-modules-load.service(8)
           man:modules-load.d(5)
  Process: 215 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-modules-load (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 215 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

I had added in /etc/default/grub

```
(1)
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_apic_instance=2 quiet"

(2)
    GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="acpi_apic_instance=2 quiet"
```

but issue not resolved with above two options.

In my /etc/modprobe.d directory following conf files are there.

```
    dkms.conf  
    fbdev-blacklist.conf
    modesetting.conf 
    open-vm-tools-dkms.conf

b@debian:/etc/modprobe.d# cat dkms.conf 
# modprobe information used for DKMS modules
#
# This is a stub file, should be edited when needed,
# used by default by DKMS.

b@debian:/etc/modprobe.d# cat fbdev-blacklist.conf 
# This file blacklists most old-style PCI framebuffer drivers.

blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist vt8623fb

b@debian:/etc/modprobe.d# cat modesetting.conf 
options cirrus modeset=1
options mgag200 modeset=1

b@debian:/etc/modprobe.d# cat open-vm-tools-dkms.conf 
install pcnet32 /sbin/modprobe -q --ignore-install vmxnet; /sbin/modprobe -q --ignore-install pcnet32 $CMDLINE_OPTS; /bin/true;
```

What is the issue ?

Comment: I may be wrong (and if I am I'm sure I'll be corrected) but "0,1" is just the way the 2 cores are named and you actually have the 2 cores.

Comment: yes, I have 2 cores and with fresh installation of OS it shows 2 cores, but after recompilation of kernel one CPU is disabled. Don't know how.